# Проблема в чтении массива

Tags: java, массивы, print

```java
City city = new City();
collect.add(city);

String[] arrSplit = delta.split(";");
city.setName(arrSplit[1]);
city.setRegion(arrSplit[2]);
city.setDistrcit(arrSplit[3]);
city.setPopulation(Integer.parseInt(arrSplit[4]));
city.setFoundation(arrSplit[5]);
collect.add(city);
```

Когда подается строка `["1"; "Адыгейск"; "Адыгея"; "Южный"; "12248";"123"]`, возникает ошибка выхода за предел массива.  Но ведь в массиве 6 элементов и я обращаюсь к 5 (то есть последнему).

Почему?  И как исправить?

Comment: если изменить на   city.setFoundation(arrSplit[arrSplit.length-1]);  то все работает,но ведь длина массива 6 то длина-1=5, то почему при обращение через длину-1 все работает?

Answer (score 1):

Для указанных данных проблема **не** воспроизводится:

```java
String delta = "[\"1\"; \"Адыгейск\"; \"Адыгея\"; \"Южный\"; \"12248\";\"123\"]";

String[] arrSplit = delta.split(";");

System.out.println("Число элементов: " + arrSplit.length + "; [5] = " + arrSplit[5]);

System.out.println(arrSplit.length);
for (int i = 0; i < arrSplit.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("arr[%d] = |%s|%n", i, arrSplit[i]);
}
```

Результат:

```
Число элементов: 6; [5] = "123"]
6
arr[0] = |["1"|
arr[1] = | "Адыгейск"|
arr[2] = | "Адыгея"|
arr[3] = | "Южный"|
arr[4] = | "12248"|
arr[5] = |"123"]|
```

---

Данный код работает для данных, разделённых в строке *ровно* одним символом `;` без пробелов.

Печать городов выполняется при помощи переопределения метода `toString` в классе `City`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<City> cities = Parsing(Arrays.asList(
            "1;Адыгейск;Адыгея;Южный;12248;123"
    ));

    cities.forEach(System.out::println);
}

static List<City> Parsing(List<String> main) {
    List<City> collect = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String delta : main) {
        City city = new City();
        String[] arrSplit = delta.split(";");

        city.setName(arrSplit[1]);
        city.setRegion(arrSplit[2]);
        city.setDistrict(arrSplit[3]);
        city.setPopulation(Integer.parseInt(arrSplit[4]));
        city.setFoundation(arrSplit[5]);

        collect.add(city);
    }
    return collect;
}
```

Результат:

```
City{name='Адыгейск', region='Адыгея', district='Южный', population=12248, foundation='123'}
```

Comment: По поводу разбиение да,тут ошибся в  вопросе,исправил,но это не главное.я тоже добавлял arrSplit.length что бы проверить, и он равен 6.Но обращаясь к 5.(city.setFoundation(arrSplit[5]);) все равно OutOfBounds.

Comment: Данная проблема к сожалению не воспрозводится для представленного кода.  Можете показать сообщение/стектрейс об ошибке?  Возможно, выполняется ещё какая-то обработка входной строки, из-за которой длина массива сокращается.

Comment: 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at com.company.breaker.Parsing(Main.java:60)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:17)'     Больше ничего со строкой не делеается,получена,разбита,сеттерами назначены,остальные работают.

Comment: Ну тогда только отлаживать в пошаговом режиме, или хотя бы залогировать входную строку, размер и элемента массива перед вызовом сеттеров.  Существующих данных недостаточно.  В предыдущем комментарии к ответу Gringo результаты представлены в дополнительно обработанном виде.

Comment: arrSplit=["1", "Адыгейск", "Адыгея", "Южный", "12248", +1 more] arrSplit=6 .Казалось бы что не так но ошибка всё та же.

Comment: нет,я искренне не понимаю что не так

Comment: Проверьте как следует входные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что переменные упорядочены и имеют индекс, начинающийся с 0 в массиве.

Comment: ну элементы распределены так 0[1] 1[Адыгейск] 2[Адыгея] 3[Южный][ 4[12248] 5 [123] . я же обращаюсь к 5 то есть к 123.я правильно понимаю?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]